# Prolog return value fro rule does not print correctly

Tags: prolog

This is the rule:

```
 get_style(S,E,R) :- echo_file('Playing_style.txt'),
               write('Enter digit opeion: '), read(S),
               write('Style: '), write(S),
               nth0(S, [ 'Technical', 'Positional',  'Attacking',   
                         'Calculating', 'Tricky', 'Dynamic', 'Practical',
                         'Intuitive', 'Logical', 'Young' ], E, R).
```

Execution gives:

```
1 ?- [echo_file].
true.

2 ?- get_style(S,E,R).
0. Technical
1. Positional
2. Attacking
3. Calculating
4. Tricky
5. Dynamic
6. Practical
7. Intuitive
8. Logical
9. Young:
Enter digit opeion: 5.
Style: 5
S = 5,
E = 'Dynamic',
R = ['Technical', 'Positional', 'Attacking', 'Calculating', 'Tricky', 'Practical', 'Intuitive', 'Logical', 'Young'] .

3 ?- write(S).
_G1211
true.

4 ?- write(E).
_G1211
true.
```

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Michael Convington's answer: the names of Prolog variables you assign do not play a role. If for any `X`, a predicate `p(X)` holds, then the same is true for any `Y` and `p(Y)`. Many prolog implementations therefore represent a variable just by an integer, which e.g. SWI Prolog printed in as `_G123`, `_G345` etc. Again depending on which implementation you use, the top level (the prompt where you enter your query) tries to be clever about variable names: it knows that the internal variable `_G123` corresponds to `S` and picks the one you entered:

```
?- X = f(Y).
X = f(Y).
```

If I make `Y` anonymous (i.e. not giving a name to the variable at all) by writing `_`, I get to see the internal name:

```
?- X = f(_).
X = f(_G123).
```

Unfortunately, `write/1` doesn't know as much as the top-level and uses the internal name. As I mentioned before, from a logical point of view the name of a variable doesn't matter. Therefore, if you want a specific term you need to substitute an atom: you just add the unification `S=spaceshuttle` to your goal:

```
?- S = spaceshuttle, write(S).
spaceshuttle
S = spaceshuttle.
```

The middle line is the output of `write/1` and the last line your answer substitution. What might confuse you is that your code uses the `'X'` notation to create an atom which start with a capital letter - usually this is a variable. In this case you ask for `'X'` to be a constant. Then, write also does what you expected:

```
?- write('S').
S
true.
```

The difference is easy to see when you try some unifications:

```
?- 'X' = 'Y'.
false.

?- f('X') = f('Y').
false.

?- X = Y.
X = Y.

?- f(X) = f(Y).
X = Y.
```

Atoms of a different name can never be the same, leading to "false". But two variables can be the same: the toplevel just gives you the condition (X is equal to Y if the variables are equal). This looks a bit circular, but if you you ask for the condition that `f(X) = f(Y)` it will still only tell you that you have to substitute `X` for `Y` i.e. whenever you replace `X` by something, you need to replace `Y` by the same (whatever it is).

I'd also recommend to take a tutorial which will tell you more about the strengths of Prolog (unification, backtracking, etc.). The [comp.lang.prolog FAQ](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/faq/faq.html) has some nice pointers (questions 8 an 14).

Comment: A leading underscore as in `_G123` *does not* indicate an anonymous variable. The only anonymous variable is `_`. Depending on the Prolog system, a variable whose name starts with an underscore _may_ not be reported as a singleton variable but that is not the same as an anonymous variable.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the comment on anonymous variables up there as it was distracting from the original question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An output like _S5234 means "this variable is not instantiated" (has no value).

Prolog variables are all local.  The variable S, E, and R cease to exist as soon as the next ?- prompt is displayed.

That is, you cannot "store values in" variables in Prolog.  The purpose of Prolog variables is to make the same value appear in more than one place in the same formula, rule, or fact.